# Sum of meromorphic functions is meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Our prof gave a proof that the sum, product and quotient of meromorphic functions can be extended to a meromorphic function.

> Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ be meromorphic and
> non-constant. Let $a \in \Omega$ with $f(a) \in \{0, \infty\}$. Then, in
> a punctured neighborhood of $a$, we can write $f(z) = g(z)
> (z-a)^{k}$, where $g$ is a holomorphic function with $g(a) \in
> \mathbb{C} \setminus {0}$.

I don't quite understand.

First of all, isn't it obvious that the sum and product is meromorphic (without the need to even extend the function)? Suppose for the sake of the argument that $a$ is a pole of function $f$ and $b$ is of function $g$. Then clearly $f+g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega \setminus \{a,b\}$ and on these two poles they are both $\infty$. Same for product.

For quotient this does not work though as we could get something like $\infty / \infty$. So we don't know if it's a pole or not. And in this case I do not understand the proof. I see what he does there, but I don't see why this prooves the statement.

If we choose two such extensions as he did in the proof, we get something like

$$\frac{g(z)}{g'(z)} \frac{(z-a)^k}{(z-b)^{k'}}$$

This is clearly holomorphic on $\Omega \setminus \{a,b\}$ but why are $a,b$ poles?

Comment: $f+g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega \setminus \{a,b\}$, but $f+g$ does not necessarily have a pole at $a$ or at $b$ (the principal parts could cancel). In that case you would still have to show that $f+g$ is holomorphic at $a$ or at $b$.